# Cocos2d-x CCSprite Memory Usage ( releasing CCSprite)

Tags: c++, memory, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game in cocos2dx v2.2.3. I did a test and I found some problem as below:

**Problem:** (In windows) When I run my game and checking TaskManager, I found my game took ~20MB memory (in average).

But After Adding these lines of code in `Init()` of my game `Layer` and Then it increases the memory usage up to 300MB.

```
CCSprite *t;
t = CCSprite::create("Character/foo1.png");  //Each picture is about 50MB
t->release();
t = CCSprite::create("Character/foo2.png");
t->release();
t = CCSprite::create("Character/foo3.png");
t->release();
t = CCSprite::create("Character/foo4.png");
t->release();
```

( I myself create these picture huge for this test)

I also checked m_uReference when `t->release();` is calling. and there `m_uReference` is becoming `0` and so It should be deleted! But why memory use is that high?

**Question:** I wonder How should I delete/remove/release a CCSprite after some time?

---

**Additional Info/Test:**

I found something that may help. After calling `t->release();` It somewhere reach :

```
CCSprite::~CCSprite(void) {
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(m_pobTexture);
}
```

But in `CC_SAFE_RELEASE(m_pobTexture);`, `m_uReference` of texture decrease from 2 to 1 and therefor the texture don't get deleted.
I did a test and make this change :

```
CCSprite::~CCSprite(void) {
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(m_pobTexture);
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(m_pobTexture);
}
```

And RAM returned to ~20MB. ( Also I know This's not the correct way and I missing something else)

Comment: cocos2d-iphone has a texture cache, i suppose cocos2d-x has one too. Try clearing that.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I agree with you about caching possibility but can't clear or delete it.Sorry but do you know how ?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Can you answer my second question maybe? (About best way to change image of existing ccsprite)

Comment: change its texture, there's got to be a property for it. As for cache check the API reference or search the code for "cache" or "texturecache" if it's not in the API ref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your code is likely to crash somewhere down the line (unless you left out some code): `CCSprite::create` returns an autoreleased `CCSprite`, which means you don't need to `.release()` it (and if you don't `.retain()` it, it's going to be deleted shortly after).

For your question: `CCSprite` needs a `CCTexture` to works (your image is loaded in memory). But `CCSprite` don't own the `CCTexture`; the `CCTexture` is managed by `CCTextureCache`.

`CCTextureCache` don't release a `CCTexture` directly when no `CCSprite` use it anymore: instead, it keeps the `CCTexture` for future usage (since loading a `CCTexture` is expensive) and only release `CCTexture` when there is not enough memory or you force it to do so, with

```
CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->removeUnusedTextures();
```

The short answer is: you shouldn't worry about memory used unless you have a real memory problem (game crashing because of lack of memory). Games are supposed to use a lot of memory.

Comment: Please add that the size of the image in the memory is also dependent on the "resolution"... say if u have a 2560x1536 size image, it will have a large memory snapshot than say a 1280x720 image. As mentioned in the answer, when creating Sprites using CREATE, u need not worry about releasing them yourself, just make sure the objects u are adding these sprites to, release them,so that they(sprites)can be autoreleased.It would be better to check who is holding these sprite, hence keeping them from being released. Also, a better way is to use Sprite sheets(loaded one time & referenced later on)